# UITabBar best practices

Tags: ios, swift, containers, uitabbar

in my application, in one of my controllers I have an UITabBar. Selecting an item in the tab bar, will change just a part of the controller.

*For example like a profile panel, where you have some fixed profile info on top, and at the bottom you have different settings. And you can switch from one setting category to another, using the tab bar.*

I was thinking to use containers, one container for each item in the tab bar, and selecting an item will bring at the top the selected container (or show/hide approach). But each of the container has some collection view, images and tableview.
And I'm concerned about memory.

So maybe, I should instantiate and destroy the containers when a tab bar item is selected, and don't use a show, hide approach.

But how can I do this from storyboard?

Comment: Why don't you use simple `UITabbarController` itself instead of using containers and managing the switching of tabs by yourself?

Comment: A "container" that shows one view controller's view at a time is a UIPageViewController. It takes care of the memory issue for you. Why not use that?

Comment: @AdilSoomro because uiTabBarController release memory only when it's deallocated. I Want to deallocate each container every time is deallocated.

Comment: @matt do you think I can use it with the UITabBarView?

Comment: I don't have any way of knowing what _you can_ do. You will have to write delegate code to respond to the tab bar selection changing, in such a way as to drive the page change in the UIPageViewController. Your talk about "do this from the storyboard" makes me think you probably don't understand how to do that. However, it is what _I would_ do if I wanted the interface you describe. But I probably would use a UISegmentedControl and not a tab bar; a tab bar without a tab bar controller is an improbable scenario.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `UITabController` then you're largely committing to the way it wants you to work. That is to say, each tab corresponds to a `UIViewController`.

However, you can use the `UITabBar` directly which gives you access to the `UITabBarDelegate`. In your delegate implementation you can respond to `UTabBarItem` selections and manipulate your `UIViewController` however you want.

There are some subtle side-effects, like:
- adjust the content insets of your `UIViewController`
- manage the state of the `UITabBar`

But there's nothing overly complex with this.

Comment: so you are saying to override the controller every time the tab bar Is selected?

Comment: Not quite, although you can. You can use the UITabBar and the delegate with flexibility. In your question it sounds like the tab bar can be used to manipulate parts of a UIViewController, or to show/hide the controllers. As for memory usage, measure the impact of each and see if really is significant.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably solved easiest doing it programmatically. Try using a UINavigationController with your Tab Bar